# Detect encoding in PHP without multibyte extension?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, multibyte

Is there a way to detect the encoding of a string in PHP without having the mbstring extension loaded? I know it is possible to do so with `mb_detect_encoding()`, but is there an equivalent, non-multibyte function?

If not, what would it take to implement a `detect_encoding()` function that would at least detect UTF-8?

Comment: detecting encoding isn't easy. a plain ascii file that uses only the 0-127 chars is also a perfectly valid utf-8 file, but you can't tell it was built with utf or with old-school ascii, because the two are indistinguishable. you could do stuff like looking for the BOM, but not all files have that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings in PHP are just byte sequences, they carry no encoding information with them. `mb_detect_encoding` doesn't actually detect the string's encoding, it tries to make an educated guess by running the byte sequence against a series of identification functions, one per encoding (by default those given by [`mb_detect_order`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-order.php)), and returns the first one in which the sequence matches. These functions are *very* basic and don't even exist for many popular encodings.

There is no way, with or without the mbstring extension, to ascertain the encoding of a string - only to *maybe* rule some out, which you could only do if the string happens to contain byte sequences that would be invalid in those particular encodings.

You will never know whether `"\xC2\xA4"` is supposed to be the UTF-8 `¤` or ISO-8859-1 `Â¤` just by looking at it - because they're the exact same bytes.

For more information see: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: thanks for that info. to the last part of my question with your logic, it should possible to detect that a string is not utf8, correct? what would that look like?

Answer (score 0):

There's always [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-get-encoding.php), which is generally enabled in PHP by default

```
<pre>
<?php
iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");
iconv_set_encoding("output_encoding", "ISO-8859-1");
var_dump(iconv_get_encoding('all'));
?>
</pre>
```

Comment: i definitely wasn't aware of those methods, but i need a way to specifically test a string